# map csv / xml files to java objects

Tags: java, xml, csv

can you please help me for choice the best java APIs to map CSV file and XML file into java objects in the context of spring boot application and micro services?
- OpenCSV, CommonApache JAXB ...? 
what are the best API for csv and XML to java objcts for a

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I used OpenCSV a lot, without any issue. You can get a good feel of it from this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv).

You will need a different library for XML. You need to choose first between [DOM and SAX](https://www.mysoftkey.com/java/difference-between-dom-and-sax-parser-in-java/). The most important criteria is size - does it fit in memory with ease? If so, use a DOM one, as it's faster. Otherwise SAX.

A good recommendation for DOM parsing is [dom4j](https://dom4j.github.io/).